# How to dynamically update context values in render_template() via GET requests?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, leaflet

I have a framework that retrieves the values of a slider via POST requests from HTML to Flask using AJAX. This calls the `/about` endpoint to perform some data manipulation and generates a redirected link defining the API url. Another endpoint (`/index`) then takes that API url and retrieves a response from the data source. However, when I attempt to render the template under the `/index` endpoint, I am unable to observe a dynamically rendering template suited for further upstream data visualization tasks.

Here's a very basic example illustrating the pipeline I've laid out:

**./templates/index.html:**

```
  <body>
      <div id="map" style="height: 700px;"></div>
      <form method = 'POST'>
        <div class="rangeslider"> 
            <input style="width: 50%;" type="range" min="0" max="64" value="64" class="myslider" id="sliderRange"> 
            <p>
                <span id="demo"></span>
            </p> 
        </div>
        
      <h1><b>Testing context value: {{ asdf }}</b></h1>

    <script> 
      const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var rangeslider = document.getElementById("sliderRange"); 
      var output = document.getElementById("demo"); 
      var current;
       
      rangeslider.oninput = function() {
          // Step 1: receives value from HTML slider object
          current = this.value;
          Http.open('POST', '/about')
          Http.send(current)
      }
     </script>
  </body>
```

**./app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return redirect('/index')

@app.route('/index', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    asdf = request.args.get('asdf')
    // Step 3: asdf undergoes request to pull in appropriate data from data source and would ideally generate custom HTML prepped to inject a child into an existing leaflet.js app 
    // Issue occurs in asdf = asdf statement. Ideally asdf will represent custom HTML dependent on slider value.
    return render_template('index.html', asdf = asdf)

@app.route('/about', methods=['POST'])
def about():
    received_data = request.data
    // Step 2: received_data undergoes further preprocessing to create API URL
    return redirect(url_for("index", asdf=str(received_data)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(port=8000)
```

I know that AJAX is typically the best solution to deal with dynamic contexts, but I am unsure how to make the appropriate fixes to suit my overall needs in this case.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think you can shorten your code, a lot unnecessary routing. But before that, is your received_data even receiving the data from request.data? Or is it an empty string? try printing that.

Comment: Yeah, I am new to both Flask and front end development, so I'm sure the routing can be better optimized. I'm happy to hear improved ways to minimize routing as well. `received_data` is properly defined when I run my Flask app and check via print statements in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can pass parameters to route:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return redirect('/index')

@app.route('/index/<asdf>', methods=['GET'])
def index(asdf):

    // Step 3: asdf undergoes request to pull in appropriate data from data source and would ideally generate custom HTML prepped to inject a child into an existing leaflet.js app 
    // Issue occurs in asdf = asdf statement. Ideally asdf will represent custom HTML dependent on slider value.
    return render_template('index.html', asdf = asdf)

@app.route('/about', methods=['POST'])
def about():
    received_data = request.data
    // Step 2: received_data undergoes further preprocessing to create API URL
    return redirect(url_for("index", asdf=str(received_data)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(port=8000)
```

Adding to optimising your code, you don't need to pass asdf to index and reload the html. You can pass asdf as a response from /about to your js and insert it into the html. This might help you.
In your app.py

```
@app.route('/about', methods=['POST'])
def about():
    received_data = request.data
    data = {'status':'success', 'xyz':received_data}
    resp = make_response(jsonify(data), 200)
    return resp
```

You may then access this response in the XMLHttp request as:

```
<script> 
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var rangeslider = document.getElementById("sliderRange"); 
var output = document.getElementById("demo"); 
var current;
 
rangeslider.oninput = function() {
    // Step 1: receives value from HTML slider object
    current = this.value;
    Http.open('POST', '/about')
    Http.send(current)
}
Http.onload = function() {
            var response = JSON.parse(Http.responseText)
            if (response['status'] == "success") {
                $('#tag').html(response['xyz'])
            }
        }
</script>
```

You may change how you use the response to your context.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response! Unfortunately, when I implement your solution (both integrated with my work, and completely separately from my work), I am getting a `127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2021 20:11:11] "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 404 -` error from the back end and a 404 Not Found error on the front end.

Comment: Can you please update with the complete error stack from the error log?